# Returning a reference to a const stuct's (pointer-type) member: apparent lvalue to rvalue conversion

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, value-categories

Given the following code, GCC gives some unexpected errors & warnings. I'm trying to return a member of a struct by reference, and it's saying that I'm returning a temporary! Also, when attempting to fix this function, it complains of a value category conversion error? In any case, as far as I know, a member access to a lvalue object should produce an lvalue, so this code should work in the first place. What is wrong?

Code: ([live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6b9822e57439fd5))

```
const struct {
    int* iptr = nullptr;
} cnst_struct;

const int* const& return_temporary_warning() {
    return cnst_struct.iptr;
}

const int*& value_cat_convert_error() {
    return cnst_struct.iptr;
}
```

Produces (GCC):

```
main.cpp: In function 'const int* const& return_temporary_warning()':
main.cpp:8:24: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return cnst_struct.iptr;
                        ^~~~
main.cpp: In function 'const int*& value_cat_convert_error()':
main.cpp:16:24: error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'const int*&' to an rvalue of type 'const int*'
     return cnst_struct.iptr;

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question can be made to compile without errors or warnings by making the struct member a pointer-to-const:

```
const struct {
    const int* iptr = nullptr;
} cnst_struct;
```

Or, by making the functions return non-const references.

The issue here (while subtle) is that the `iptr` member is not the exact same type as the decayed type of the reference that is being returned, and so conversions are attempted. There is one, namely `int*` -> `const int*` but the result of this conversion is a rvalue, and hence all the warnings and errors.

Also, Clang produces a different warning, that is perhaps more helpful:

```
main.cpp:8:12: warning: returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return cnst_struct.iptr;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:16:12: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const int *' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'int *const'
    return cnst_struct.iptr;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```